# Django admin css not being applied after loading

Tags: css, django

I am using nginx to serve my django static files. In the browser I can see that they are loaded, base.css, login.css, responsive.css all got status 200, I can click on them and see their content.

The problem is that they don't seem to be applied in the html. The html still looks like it has no css formatting applied to it at all. There are no errors in the nginx logs and no errors in the network tab in chrome. I have tried chrome and firefox

Using Django 2.2.4

Relevant nginx config

```
server {
    listen          8000;
    server_name     127.0.0.1;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/<SECRET_PATH>/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/<SECRET_PATH>/dashboard.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check  if the static url is correct in your django application?

Comment: If you are running `collectstatic` and still it doesn't work (like you said that CSS files load), does the server return proper mime types for CSS files?

Comment: @Rehmat I see in chrome that the type is stylesheet

Comment: @ruddra I assume its correct since nginx is serving those files to the browser

Comment: @Dale Can you mention the URL if the site isn't private?

Comment: @Rehmat the site is private so it cannot be shared. Looking at the reponse header content type i see *text/plain* and not *text/css*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like proper mime type isn't returned for the CSS files. In your NGINX conf, generally it is located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, ensure that you have included the mimes like:

`include  "/etc/nginx/mime.types";`

And in your mimes, ensure that proper mime type is set for the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the response headers I saw the mime type was text (as @Rehmat suggested). The fix was to add the mime types in the server block

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

this solved the problem

Comment: Glad, just posted the answer :)